# PHP assigning a function from a class

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a function to assign a class in my php code, but whenever I declare this function from another file or code I get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function.....

For example my code

```
function TophiveCore(){
    return TophiveCore::getInstance();
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(TophiveCore::getInstance(), 'init') );
```

this file also contains the `TophiveCore` class with a function`getInstance()` but its not working..Suppose I like to use `TophiveCore()->get_url()` it comes

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function`

Answer (score 0):

use `require_once('class.php');` in top of your file. If you trying to follow singleton design pattern, make `Tophivecore()` as static function.

PHP singleton example: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton/php/1